AES-256-CBC IONIC encrypted data is not able to decrypt in PHP
I am encrypting text in IONIC using @ionic-native/aes-256/ngx library and trying to decrypt the same in PHP but am unable to do so.
Here's the data :
Key :  12345678901234567890123456789012 (32bit)
IV : 1234567890123456
Plain Text : ABCD

Encrypted in IONIC : W2/PbR8z0sKBblfd4ezO1DKI/7UrB/egwDEGyw7w9tY=
It's decrypting in IONIC but not in PHP.
In PHP I tried encryption of the same text using the same keys but also I am getting different encrypted data.
PHP encrypted data for string ABCD : 5JvCGZhhM12hA9Tz/ldBvw==
Can somebody please explain if I am missing anything?
import { AES256 } from ‘@ionic-native/aes-256/ngx’;

constructor(public aes:AES256){}

encrypt(key, iv, data){
    return this.aes.encrypt(key, iv, data);
}

output : "W2/PbR8z0sKBblfd4ezO1DKI/7UrB/egwDEGyw7w9tY= "

$iv = “1234567890123456”;
$key = “12345678901234567890123456789012”;
$encrypted = "W2/PbR8z0sKBblfd4ezO1DKI/7UrB/egwDEGyw7w9tY= ";

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, “AES-256-CBC”, $key, 0, $iv);

echo $decrypted;

Encrypted data in IONIC and PHP are different. I want to decrypt the text in PHP which was done using IONIC

@ionic-native/aes-256 references this repository with a TypeScript implementation of AES256, which in turn references this repository with an Android implementation of AES256.

This logic uses a key derivation, namely PBKDF2 with SHA-1, 1001 iterations and the static salt hY0wTq6xwc6ni01G. With this, the ciphertext can indeed be decrypted, namely as Base64 string: arqWj4Qs3nDX5iYw9blqyA==. An incorrect decryption is unlikely due to the valid padding with seven 0x07 bytes.

However, the result does not match the plaintext ABCD that you expect. So either your expectation is wrong or the result is possibly a second ciphertext whose decryption results in ABCD.

Using the given plaintext, algorithm, key, and iv the base64'd ciphertext output is: 5JvCGZhhM12hA9Tz/ldBvw== whose decoded length is 16 bytes. What you have give as an example ciphertext has a decoded length of 32 bytes. This implies to me that you are using a longer and therefore wholly different plaintext input for your Ionic test code, to say nothing of if the key and IV match.
